# Fix Plymouth with Nvidia driver in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: plymouth

Using the Nvidia driver, how can Plymouth be fixed in Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)?

In other versions there was a script that fixed it, but it is not working in Ubuntu 13.10 and package `hwinfo` is missing, but with free drivers it is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround in few steps:

1. Backup your `sources.list`: `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list_backup`
2. Just add previous release repo (located [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/configuration.html)) to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Download and run [this script](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/121675171/fixplymouth)
4. Put your `sources.list` back: `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list_backup /etc/apt/sources.list` and execute `sudo apt-get update`

After, you can download and change some plymouth themes:

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-solar
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution (alternative one works in my case but you must adapt a little some terminal commands to ubuntu 13.10) ;)

[Plymouth fix](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml)

Answer (score -1):

1. sudo apt-get install libhal1
2. sudo apt-get install libhd16
3. sudo apt-get install hwinfo
4. download and run this [script](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/121675171/fixplymouth)

Comment: but hwinfo does not work for ubuntu 13.10

Comment: if u dont trust my answer then dont try. my ubuntu 13.10 here is working fine with nvidia drivers and plymouth.

Comment: I disagree. This isn't about trust, it is about facts: Ubuntu 13.10  doesn't ship with hwinfo. See [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/hwinfo) at the bottom.

Comment: it is a little too late to say this now , since 13.10 is history , but i have to say it. Sorry for ignoring it at that time.
Yes hwinfo didnt come preinstalled in 13.10 but if we install libhal1 and libhd16 we can then install hwinfo and get plymouth fixed. A linux operating system is an open code operating system and we can do anything we want. It doesnt matter at all if something is missing or not working , if we can just fixed it with a little knowledge... Anyway, thats history now...