# How do I fix ugly boot screen glitch in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: plymouth

Normally, the boot screen should says 'ubuntu' with five orange dots below it, but in my pc, they suddenly turn into this:

[image]

- [Glitched boot screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkbMq.jpg)
- [Glitched boot screen 8 seconds video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9FSJIOClI0)

Here is my hardware:

- Intel Core2Quad Q9550
- HIS HD 4670 IceQ
- Asus P5Q

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try the solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6033/enabling-nvidia-driver-messes-up-splash-screen). It's also supposed to work for AMD cards.

Comment: Have you checked this out>

http://askubuntu.com/questions/362470/fix-plymouth-with-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: @mikewhatever : I tried every solutions in that question, the only one that partially works is the last one (posted by DanFritz). It solved the glitch, but lowered my screen resolution down from 1600x900 (16:9) to 1152x864 (4:3).

Comment: @gdesilva : That script lowered my screen resolution too, and didn't even solved the glitch.